# while inserting Google calendar entries using service account and.NET giving error

Tags: .net

While trying to insert calendar event to one user's account it is returning error form me as

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError  Not Found [404]  Errors [
>           Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
>       ]
>
> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>       Not Found [404]
>       Errors [
>           Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
>       ]

```
    public static Event insert(CalendarService service, string id, Event myEvent){    
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event calenderEvent = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();
calenderEvent.Summary = myEvent.Summary;
                //calenderEvent.Description = summary;
                //calenderEvent.Location = summary;
                calenderEvent.Start = new  Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 07, 07, 19, 00, 0),
                    //DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    TimeZone = "(GMT+05:30) India Standard Time"//,
                                                                //TimeZone = "Europe/Istanbul"
                };
                calenderEvent.End = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 07, 07, 18, 00, 0),
                    //DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                    TimeZone = "(GMT+05:30) India Standard Time"//,
                                                                //TimeZone = "Europe/Istanbul"
                };enter code here
var newEventRequest = service.Events.Insert(calenderEvent, id);
                newEventRequest.SendNotifications = true;
                var eventResult = newEventRequest.Execute();

                return eventResult;
}
```

Comment: hello ... any luck with this ? I'm facing same issue